# How JSP pages handle a not defined variable in Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, internet-explorer

In my Spring Controller

```
@Controller
class DummyController{

@Requestmapping
public String testBlopGhostController{
model.addattributes ( "yop", false );
return nameOfJspPage;
}
```

Then in my Jsp page:

```
<c:if test ="${yop}">
<c:if test ="${blop}">
<p>One who stands straight doesn't fear a crooked shadow.</p>
</c:if>
</c:if>
```

Even if didn't add blop variable in the model, there is no JspException and no logs in the browser.

How Jsp handle this kind of situations (in case of multiple not defined variables used in jsp test balises)?

Comment: The variables not defined in the controllers are evaluated to false. But what is the good practices when we use multiples variables some of them are not defined and we use may conditions in jsp <c:if ? thanks folks

Comment: What behavior did you observe when you tried it? Do you have a hypothesis?

Comment: chrylis, the behavior i just observed is that any block that use a condition <c:if test ="${!variable}"> ..</c:if> is evaluated to true, the variable not defined -> false -> !false -> true so we display the block.